# PHP preg_replace replace between slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a PHP function which is supposed to remove a value with its starting `/` and ending `/` from a given URL.

for example: remove `/page_###/` from `http://my-domain.com/search/page_2/order_asc`.
the result will be: `http://my-domain.com/search/order_asc`.

but also the URL may be like this: `http://my-domain.com/search/order_asc/page_2`. there is no ending `/` in the end;

```
function stripDir($url, $mask){
    return preg_replace('/' . $mask . '[\s\S]+?/', '', $url);
}
```

the above function should be able to remove `page_5` from following URLS...
`stripDir('http://my-domain.com/search/page_5/order_asc', 'page')` and `stripDir('http://my-domain.com/search/order_asc/page_5', 'page')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/`s in your current regular expression are [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), not the starting and ending characters you are looking for. Try changing the delimiter and it should work. Also if the trailing `/` is optional you should modify the regex I think:

```
~/page_[\s\S]+?(/|\z)~
```

or per your function:

```
~/' . $mask . '[\s\S]+?(/|\z)~
```

would work for you.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sH7bE2/3 
Demo of just modified delimiters: https://regex101.com/r/sH7bE2/2 
Demo of original regex: https://regex101.com/r/sH7bE2/1

Also since you are checking for the starting and ending `/` you're going to want to re-place one of those `/`s.

With substitution demo: https://regex101.com/r/sH7bE2/4

Answer (score 2):

```
function stripDir($url, $mask) {
    return preg_replace('/\/' . preg_quote($mask, '/') . '[^\/]+/', '', $url);
}
```

Comment: Answers should have a write up with them.